# show off mobile sites in web portfolio?

Tags: html, mobile

Does anyone out there know if its possible to show a working version of a mobile site in a web portfolio?  Wondered if there was an emulator that could be used for this purpose?

Any ideas, please give me a shout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using device detection on the mobile site, the easiest way would be to have a flag in your URL that will make the site think it's serving a mobile client and not a web client. This depends on your implementation, but spoofing the device is the easiest way. Makes it easier to debug as well.

Comment: Hi John, cheers for the advice - how would I include this in my portfolio though - I just want to show an example of a mobile version!?  I guess I could work your solution by running the mobile app in an iframe?

Comment: @Paul yeah you'd run it in an iframe or a resized  popup. The UA can be switched with extensions, but it's easier for user if you trigger the behavior for them.

Answer (score 0):

this site shows samples of mobile sencha touch apps running in an iphone

http://www.synthphone.com/

below is a sample URL that links directly to google mobile site on a device with dimensions 320 x 480 (iPhone)

http://www.synthphone.com/?u=http://m.google.com&w=320&h=480

hope this gives you some ideas at least